# login screen security flaw

Tags: magento-1.9, login

Whenever I go to the admin page of my store it shows the password filled in already:

[image].

A malicious user would only have to guess the user name to gain access.

I checked chrome's saved password and the webstore url is explicitly excluded. How can this behaviour be changed?

Comment: did you tried cleaning the cache from your browser?

Comment: Clear your saved password and clear your cookies in history. then try it will works

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a magento issue. It appears because browser autocomplete. The username is empty because the values is cleared on focus.

Answer (score 2):

This is a browser property and have nothing to do with magento. You can remove the saved password by clearing your browser history for now. Next time when you login don't save the password if the browser shows a save password notification popup window.
Thanks.